# Is it a good practice to include the complete authorization uri in an <a> tag?

Tags: html, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm working on a web application and I'm trying to integrate Google's OAuth 2.0 in my application. I can generate the authorization URI but my question is that is it a good practice to include this URI inside an `<a>` tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal thing to do is to cook up that URL and then, rather than put in a document with an  tag in order for someone to click on it, actually launch an HTTP GET to that URL directly from your program, using whatever HTTP library you like.

If you wanted the user to launch the authentication process manually I guess there would be no reason in principle why you couldn't wrap it in an  and offer it to them that way.